# What's the difference between "volumeDevices" vs "volumeMounts" with k8s v1.13

Tags: kubernetes, linux-device-driver

Running `kubectl explain pod.spec.containers` shows:

```
   volumeDevices    <[]Object>
     volumeDevices is the list of block devices to be used by the container.
     This is a beta feature.

   volumeMounts <[]Object>
     Pod volumes to mount into the container's filesystem. Cannot be updated.
```

Is there a relationship between these two containers properties?

Note that `kubectl version` shows:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13",
>   GitVersion:"v1.13.0",
>   GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T21:04:45Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
>
> Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0",
>   GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T20:56:12Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'volumeDevices' is part of a new beta feature in 1.13 that allows a pod to access a raw block volume instead of a mounted filesystem volume.  This is useful for some advanced applications like databases that may have their own filesystem format.

You can find the official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#raw-block-volume-support) although it does not seem to be updated for 1.13 yet.